# E254: Cannot allocate color SlateBlue

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

I just freshly installed `vim` via `brew install vim`... and presently have version `8.2.3450`.

In `~/.vimrc` I have `syntax on`, and when I run `vim`, I get:

```
E254: Cannot allocate color SlateBlue
```

If I delete / comment out `syntax on`, then there is no problem, but also no color.

I found this https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/945 and was told to come here :)

I found this https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/rgb.txt and had a problem:

```
-bash> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/master/runtime/rgb.txt -o ~/Downloads/rbg.txt
-bash> mv !$ /usr/share/vim/vim82/
mv: /usr/share/vim/vim82/rbg.txt: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: you need to be a superuser to write to `/usr/share`.  So do you not have `rgb.txt` inside `/usr/share/vim/vim82/` folder? I am not sure, but it might work if `rgb.txt` lives inside `~/.vim/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out that there is no `~/.vim` folder, and when I make one and place `rgb.txt` into it, this has no effect on the situation. No, I do not have `rgb.txt` inside `/usr/share/vim/vim82/`, as per `find /usr/share/vim/ -name rgb.txt`. Also, I just found that I cannot edit `/usr/share` even as `root` and that's because `/usr`, except for `/usr/local` is protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP)... see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301976/mac-os-x-wont-let-me-mkdir-usr-share-tomcat6-even-as-root.

Comment: hm, in that case I don't know how make it work. It may work, to compile your own version, place it under e.g. `/usr/local` and then make `$VIMRUNTIME` point to that directory.

Comment: or alternatively, what also should work: just clone the vim repo to e.g. `~/vim-source/` and then use `export $VIMRUNTIME=~/vim-source/runtime`

Comment: Cloning the `vim` repo (https://github.com/vim/vim) and exporting `VIMRUNTIME` did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your gh issue (which I found first) and then this post - it took far too long to debug this problem. I'm now leaving an answer here to add some more keywords related to this issue so other people can find this question.

In my case, I manually compiled & installed a fresh pull of gh/vim/vim master (8.2.3582) on linux mint (ubuntu).
I got some of the following errors:

```
failed to load colors/lists/default.vim
Error detected while processing /home/me/.vimrc[8]../usr/local/share/vim/vim82/defaults.vim[120]../usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim[19]../usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim[21]../usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim:
line   53:
E254: Cannot allocate color SlateBlue
failed to load colors/lists/default.vim
line   36:
E254: Cannot allocate color Orange
```

The problem is caused by vim failing to install all the runtime deps to a location it knows to look for; in this case, rgb.txt file is missing (along with many others!).
The solution was mentioned in the comments above by @Christian Brabandt. Having pulled & compiled vim, there is a `(vim repo)/runtime/` subfolder with all the needed files; so I added the following line to my `.bashrc` (or for mac(?) `.profile`) to tell vim where to look for runtime deps.

```
export VIMRUNTIME=~/path/to/vim(repo)/runtime/
```

Comment: as mentioned in the github issue. With a recent vim build, Vim does no longer depend on rgb.txt. So it's dependency has been removed. The question is: did you run `make install`? Vim should then copy the runtime files **somewhere**. Also, can you show the output of `:version` so we can check.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: (Moved the discussion to the above gh issue. But yes, did run sudo make install, and full text output of :version is in the gh issue above (but reports 8.2.3582 with gtk3 and python3))